GCP Table Widget - Filter Records by Metric's Latest Value During selected Time Range
I'm trying to filter  table widget records by its latest value during selected time range with no success.
my application exposes a custom gauge metric representing a state of a process.
The metric has a label that holds the process state , the metric v value can be 0 or 1  - 1 will be the value of the current state.
my process can be on one of the following states: export/import/done/error.
the process exposes a metric called coldstartstate.
on each time interval 4 values of the metric will be exposed (one for each state) only one of them will have the value 1.(which is the current state)
see below the metric output in a specific timestamp:
(https://i.sstatic.net/mdvupfND.png)
I'm trying to create a table dashboard that will contain  the last state in a given time range.  I created a table widget built from the following promoql
((last_over_time(coldstartstate[${__interval}])))==1
My issue is when cold start process state is changed during the selected time range  - in this case I'll receive the previous state as well (even though its last exposed value during this time range is  0)
below a output sample : (https://i.sstatic.net/6Hse0GBM.png)
During the selected time range the state was changed from error to export  - when I'm trying to get all metric records which their last value is 1  - I get the export record and the error record as well.
